# Jetty - path requires trailing slash

Tags: jetty

So I have a Jetty container with a URL like this: http://localhost:7071/my-app-name/ui/. The problem I'm running into is that Jetty seems to require that last trailing slash.

So this works:

http://localhost:7071/my-app-name/ui/

But this doesn't:

http://localhost:7071/my-app-name/ui

It's really weird, I would want the slash-less path to go to the same place as the path with a slash. That path is the homepage of the entire application, which is why I want it to work.

Here is some of my Jetty configuration.

PS. I'm working in Kotlin. The principles of how it works should still be the same though.

```
server = Server(props.getProperty(AppProps.PORT).toInt())
val handler = ServletContextHandler(server, root)
val appServletHolder = ServletHolder("AppServlet", AppServlet::class.java)
handler.addServlet(appServletHolder, "/ui/*")
handler.addEventListener(AppCore(props))
server.start()
```

I know I'm specifying "/ui/*" in my servlet holder configuration. But I can't seem to figure out any way to change that, I've tried a few combinations and none of them work better.

Answer (score 2):

You've told the servlet spec that you want to listen on `/ui/*` so it mandates that your URLs must have the `/ui/` portion.

But all is not lost, just tell the servlet spec the other url-patterns you are also interested in.  (Servlets can be mapped to as many url-patterns as you want)

aka:

```java
server = Server(props.getProperty(AppProps.PORT).toInt());
val handler = ServletContextHandler(server, root);
val appServletHolder = ServletHolder("AppServlet", AppServlet::class.java);
handler.addServlet(appServletHolder, "/ui"); // <-- like that
handler.addServlet(appServletHolder, "/ui/*");
handler.addEventListener(AppCore(props));
server.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a bunch of duplicate servlet mappings, I added one at the root to redirect any requests ending with "/" or "/index.html":

```
...
servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(RedirectServlet.class, "/*");
servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(AnotherServlet.class, "/ui");
...
```

```
public class RedirectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();
        if(pathInfo.endsWith("/") || pathInfo.endsWith("/index.html")) {
            String newPath = pathInfo.substring(0, pathInfo.lastIndexOf('/'));
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            resp.setHeader("Location", newPath);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```